# Why the AnchorPoint doesn't affect the `CCLayer` Positioning?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, coordinates, cocos2d-x, layers

I think there is a difference between the CCLayer and CCNode behavior when I change their AnchorPoint.

I will describe what I mean and please somebody explain it.

**Scenario:**
I start with `CCNode`

```
CCNode *node = ...;
node.setContentSize(ccp(W,H));
// 1.
node.setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
node.setPosition(ccp(X,Y); // This line will move the node in a way that its (0,0)-point will be placed at (X,Y).
// 2.
node.setAnchorPoint(ccp(1,1));
node.setPosition(ccp(X,Y); // This line will move the node in a way that its (0,0)-point will be placeed at (X-W,Y-H).
//In other word, this line will move the (W,H)-point of the node to (X,Y)
```

In addition to the **Positioning**, all actions (like **Rotating, Scaling**) are based on this anchor point.

This policy is fair enough and you won't get confused when moving a scaled node (`setScale(X)`) to some position because the **node's position** ( and **not node's contents!**) will not change in the screen after any actions.

( **PS:** We knew that rotating/scaling a node will rotate/scale internal node contents)

Let's continue with `CCLayer`:

```
CCLayer *layer= ...;
layer.setContentSize(ccp(W,H));
// 1.
layer.setAnchorPoint(ccp(0,0));
layer.setPosition(ccp(X,Y); // This line will move the layer in a way that its (0,0)-point will be placed at (X,Y)
// 2.
layer.setAnchorPoint(ccp(1,1));
layer.setPosition(ccp(X,Y); // Unfortunately, This line will move the layer in a way that its (0,0)-point will be placeed at (X,Y).
```

Although CCLayer also use the anchor point for scaling, rotating and ... purposes, **It does NOT use its anchor point for positioning!!!**

Question >>>>  **WHY? and How can I have the same CCNode-like `setPosition()` behaviour for `CCLayer`?**

---

PS: I've also tried `->ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(true)` but it didn't help.

(@cocos2d-x version is 2.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

You say you have tried setting `ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(true), but have you tried setting it to false?

CCLayer init method calls `ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(true)`, which basically tells cocos to ignore the anchor point for positioning. You can set it to false and it should respect the anchor point for position.